# Why Does Heavy Workout Make Me Want to Wear Sweater

Tags: post-workout

I have noticed after tennis matches, the athletes will wear coats even though they are sweating profusely.

After heavy workout, I notice I need to wear heavy sweater, even though it is 90 degrees outside.

Is this a good practice? What is the medical reason for this?

Comment: I know a couple of people whose perceived body temperature swings for a few hours after a workout (sweats and chills, as if they had a fever). Both have chronic health issues, however, which makes isolating a suspected cause tricky. A lighter workout helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Is this a good practice?**

**No**. This is unnecessary for people like us. The only reason that I can think off, is that they want get rid of sodium.

**What is the medical reason for this?**

I don't think there is a medical reason to this. I could be wrong for all I know.